# How to implement such an element via html/css

Tags: html, css

I need to implement an element like on the picture, but I don't know how to do it.
https://image.prntscr.com/image/ipRuSmXpRV2B6RjBj6r07Q.png

I have tried to do this via , when first cell has values of years, second has a "split" implemented by ::before and :: after and third has description. But my solution doesn't work.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="years">2011 - 2015</td>
        <td>
            <div class="split"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="info">
            Your description gives people the information they need to help you answer your question.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.split {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.split::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}

.split::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px dashed black;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not possible in the table you can make with div tag easily.

Comment: Indeed, a `table` is not even close to the optimal layout method.

Comment: Could you tell me the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of playing around on code pen, I managed to implement this without using any 3rd party libraries or frameworks, just plain old HTML & CSS:

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure > div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#d2:before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div id="d1">This is</div>
  <div id="d2">&bull;</div>
  <div id="d3">Incredible</div>
</figure>

<figure>
  <div id="d1">This is</div>
  <div id="d2">&bull;</div>
  <div id="d3">Incredible</div>
</figure>
 
<figure>
  <div id="d1">This is</div>
  <div id="d2">&bull;</div>
  <div id="d3">Incredible</div>
</figure>
```

**NOTE:** In case you can't run this snippet, here's a working [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgzgvB).

**NOTE:** You might have to modify the height of the red (you can change that color) *"border"* in some of the figures if the 1st/3rd siblings are larger than the 2nd sibling.

Good luck.